# Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.DesignPackageType' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client'

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell, office-dev-pnp

When I try to load "Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell" got below error. Not sure where I am going wrong here.

> Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell 16.0.8924.1200
>
> SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline          3.9.1905.3

[image]

Comment: looks like version mismatch, could you please check this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33301.sharepoint-online-troubleshooting-import-module-could-not-load-assembly-version-issue.aspx

Comment: Thanks for sharing the article. I have looked into it and it talks about different DLL "Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant". For me the issue is with "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" when I search the dll found only one module with that DLL which is "Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell"

Comment: I also don't have "SharePoint Online Management Shell" installed instead would like to use Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell module

Comment: I uninstalled all modules related to SharePoint "Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell" and "SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline". Then I also uninstalled "SharePoint Online Client Components SDK". Once all of these has been uninstalled I again installed "Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell" and "SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline" and issue is fixed. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Issue also can be related with several instances of SPO SDKs installed. In this case try the following steps:

1. Open Control Panel -> UnInstall Programs -> Search for SharePoint related setups.
2. Locate SharePoint Client Components -> Uninstall.
3. Locate SharePoint Online Management Shell -> Uninstall.
4. Ensure that anyone of the above setup is installed more than one time. If so, remove all the instances.
5. Now, open the Powershell console in administrative mode (Run as administrator).
6. Uninstall SPO Powershell module (If already exists) by running this command: Uninstall-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -AllVersions -Force
7. Finally, install the latest SPO Powershell module by running this command: Install-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -Force